# Access SonarQube Port 9000 outside (publicly) the Azure VM

Tags: azure, networking, sonarqube, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I configured SonarQube on Azure VM (Windows). Everything working as expected. Only thing is I can not access SonarQube portal outside my Azure VM. I whitelisted port in firewall as well as subnet NSG but didn't work. I tried accessing it through VM Public IP as well as DNS but none worked.

Port: 9000

Is there any specific configuration required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have everything working as expected after you configured SonarQube on Azure VM (Windows). You should see the sonar home screen via open a browser and open `http://localhost:9000/`.

Make sure you add a rule to the Windows firewall. You could open a command prompt as an administrator on Azure VM and run the following command.

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=Sonar dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=9000
```

Add Inbound security rules in NSG.

[image]

Then you should be able to access it via `http://<public IP address of VM>:9000`.

You could get more details [here](https://writeabout.net/2016/04/25/setup-sonarqube-in-azure-vm/) and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: you made my day. Firware configuration was only missing part in my configuration. For curosity - why we need additional firewal setting while we are already allowing particular port through Inbound Rule?

Comment: NSG is used for Azure subnet or nic level firewall, but by default, there is a windows firewall inside the Azure VM unless you have disabled it.